# yum should error when a package is not available

Tags: centos, yum, centos5

I recently ran into a bug in a script where I tried to do the following:

```
yum -y install another_package.x86_64 some_package.x86_64 && run_my_script
```

The script ran well on a newer CentOS, but when I tried to execute it on Cent OS 5, `some_package.x86_64` was not available. But instead of erroring and stopping `yum` just printed the message:

```
No package some_package.x86_64 available.
```

How can I force `yum` to error in such situations (which IMO should be the default) to make my scripts more robust?

Comment: Build your script more rebust and check for return value of yum before going on.

Comment: @frlan That is the issue. `yum` happily returns `0` in this case. My script is already checking the return value before proceeding. Notice the `&&`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've found, this behaviour changed between RHEL 5 and 6 (see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=736694 for some discussion). From that link, checking the return code of `yum info <pkg>` should allow you to abort your script as required. Something like:

```
# Set a variable containing the packages to install:
pkgs_to_install='another_package.x86_64 some_package.x86_64'

# Loop over the packages in the list:
for pkg in ${pkgs_to_install}; do
  # Stop executing if at least one package isn't available:
  yum info ${pkg} >> /dev/null 2>&1 || exit
done

# Continue running your original script:
yum -y install ${pkgs_to_install} && run_my_script
```

Comment: OK, that helps and confirms that I'm not crazy to think that this should be the default.

Comment: helps well, the current yum behavior is quite unfriendly for script usage.

Answer (score 22):

Per [Bug 1274211](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1274211), this has been fixed in yum-3.4.3-133.el7.  However, you need to enable the strict mode.

The easiest way to do this for scripting purposes is via command-line switch:

```
yum -y --setopt=skip_missing_names_on_install=False install another_package.x86_64 some_package.x86_64 && run_my_script
```

However, you can also set it as a configuration option in your `yum.conf`:

```
[main]
skip_missing_names_on_install=0
```